# how to get contact list using cordova on android

Tags: android, cordova

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.ContactManager
```

returnn 404 not found.

How can I get the contact list of the user using cordova on android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really a two-parter.

You are getting a 404 because that plugin doesn't exist, instead we can use the contacts plugin.  If you are using Cordova 5+ you can install from npm with: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts` if you are using an older version, use `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts` or `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts.git` for the unstable repo.

Here is an example I have adapted from the official docs, and should return all your contacts:

```
var options      = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter   = ""; //we aren't filtering on anything
options.multiple = true;
var fields       = ["*"]; //search all the fields
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
```

So we use the find method, where we pass in the desired fields to search on, our success and error callbacks, and the options for the search (which are no filter and multiple results.

See the official [docs for the contacts plugin here.](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts)